# Is it possible to pass in function with parameter that does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing

Really sorry if the title does not make sense.  Not sure how to make my question short

What I am wondering is,

I have a `recursive function`, well doesn't have to be `recursive function` just when I am doing this function, I wondered if it can be reused in a more flexiable way.

my function looks like this `runAxios(ele, api)` is the function I wonder if can be reused

```
const ct = (arr, num, res) => {
  const promises = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    const ele = arr.shift();  // take out 1st array, literally take out
    if(ele){
      promises.push(
        runAxios(ele, api)  // this is the function I am wondering if can be reused
      )
    }
  }

  Promise.all.......
};
```

if `runAxios(ele, api)` can be anything then I believe this `ct` can be a lot more flexiable?

I am wondering if it could it something like

```
const ct = (arr, num, res, fx) => {
  const promises = [];

  for loop......
    if(ele){
      promises.push(
         fx  // this is then passed as any other function other than just a fixed `axios function` that I wrote
      )
    }
  }

Promise.all........

};
```

when I first tried it, I realized this will not work because `runAxios`'s first parameter is done inside the loop which means the variable does not exist yet until it's inside the function itself.

Just being curious if there is such way to easily do it that I just don't know how or it's actually not possible?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done. You just have to call the function passed with the required paramemeters. You will calculate the ele parameter and then pass it to the function. A generic example to see the way it works is shown below:

```js
const functionToBeCalled = (parameter1, parameter2) => {
  console.log(parameter1 + parameter2);
}

const ct = (fx) => {
  //..code
    let ele = 1;
    fx(ele, 2);
  //..code
};

ct(functionToBeCalled);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your approach. It should look something like this:

```js
const someFunction = (x) => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(x));

const ct = (arr, fn) => {
  const promises = arr.filter(x => x).map(x => fn(x));
  
  Promise.all(promises).then(x => console.log(x));
};

ct([1, 2, 3], someFunction);
```

(I also took the liberty to replace your loop with a more compact approach.)